# Menu not showing up in activity and also showing some bugs but i didnt get to identify them

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, drop-down-menu, menu

**this is my mainactivity.kt file**

```
package com.example.everythingcalci

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.material3.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            EverythingCalciApp()

            val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.Calci)
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.simple_interest_calculator -> {
                setContent {
                    SimpleInterestCalculator()
                }
                true
            }
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun EverythingCalciApp() {
    Column {
        TopAppBar(
            title = { Text(text = "EverythingCalc") }, // Typo: Calci -> Calc
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
        CalculateContent()
    }
}

@Composable
fun CalculateContent() {
    var num1 by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var num2 by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var operator by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var result by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
    ) {
        TextField(
            value = num1,
            onValueChange = { num1 = it },
            label = { Text("Enter the first number") }
        )

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))

        TextField(
            value = num2,
            onValueChange = { num2 = it },
            label = { Text("Enter the second number") }
        )

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))

        TextField(
            value = operator,
            onValueChange = { operator = it },
            label = { Text("Enter the operator (+, -, *, /)") }
        )

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))

        Button(onClick = {
            result = when (operator) {
                "+" -> (num1.toFloatOrNull() ?: 0f) + (num2.toFloatOrNull() ?: 0f)
                "-" -> (num1.toFloatOrNull() ?: 0f) - (num2.toFloatOrNull() ?: 0f)
                "*" -> (num1.toFloatOrNull() ?: 0f) * (num2.toFloatOrNull() ?: 0f)
                "/" -> {
                    val n2 = num2.toFloatOrNull()
                    if (n2 != null && n2 != 0f) {
                        (num1.toFloatOrNull() ?: 0f) / n2
                    } else {
                        0f
                    }
                }
                else -> 0f
            }.toString()
        }) {
            Text("Calculate")
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))

        Text("Result: $result")
    }
}

@Composable
fun SimpleInterestCalculator() {
    var amount by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var interest by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var time by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var result by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
    ) {
        TextField(
            value = amount,
            onValueChange = { amount = it },
            label = { Text("Enter the principal amount") }
        )

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))

        TextField(
            value = interest,
            onValueChange = { interest = it },
            label = { Text("Enter the interest rate") }
        )

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))

        TextField(
            value = time,
            onValueChange = { time = it },
            label = { Text("Enter the time (in years)") }
        )

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))

        Button(onClick = {
            val resultValue = (amount.toFloatOrNull() ?: 0f) * (interest.toFloatOrNull() ?: 0f) * (time.toFloatOrNull() ?: 0f) / 100
            result = resultValue.toString()
        }) {
            Text("Calculate")
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))

        Text("Simple Interest: $result")
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun PreviewMainActivity() {
    EverythingCalciApp()
}
```

Could you please help me with menu and bugs in the code. If you need anymore images or code file I will post here

I'm encountering an issue with my Android app where the menu is not showing in the activity. I've tried several approaches but haven't been able to resolve it. Below are the relevant details:

1. **Problem**: When I run my app, the menu options defined in the XML file do not appear in the activity toolbar.
2. **What I've Tried: Here's what I've attempted so far**:    - Checked the menu XML file for correctness.    - Inflated the menu in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method of the activity.    - Ensured that the toolbar is properly set as the support action bar.    - Reviewed the activity layout XML to ensure proper inclusion of the toolbar.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

change this code

```
 Scaffold(topBar = {
        CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
            title = {
                Text(
                    text = title!!,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.iran_sans_mobile_bold)),
                    color = Color(0xFF323232),
                )
            },
            navigationIcon = {
                IconButton(onClick = { onClick() }) {
                    Icon(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.arrowdown),
                        contentDescription = "back",
                        tint = Color(0xFF323232),
                    )
                }
            },
        )
    },
        snackbarHost = {
            addToBasket(data, context)
        }

    ) { i -> // orther design }
```

in the this code

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
 @Composable
 fun EverythingCalciApp() {
Column {
    TopAppBar(
        title = { Text(text = "EverythingCalc") }, // Typo: Calci -> Calc
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    )
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
    CalculateContent()
}
 }
```